# How to treat additional parameters on Rails model creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a register form for users to sign up to my rails app and I added a checkbox for users who do not want a special service. Here is the code from the view :

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<%= f.check_box :wantsaoc, :onchange => "check_field(this)" %>
[etc...]
<% end %>
```

In my model i have a wantsaoc method thats returns me a boolean depanding on some other attributes.

How can i handle the creation so that i can catch the wantsaoc parameter and behave depending on it ?

Answer (score 2):

[Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) are hooks into the life cycle of an Active Record object that allow you to trigger logic before or after an alteration of the object state. For example,

```
class User < AR::Base
  ..
  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    if wantsoac.eql?('true')
      .. # Do something
    end
  end
end
```

Go through various callbacks you can use and choose when and what you need to do.

Comment: I already tested it, but if i actually can do additional stuff before building the object, but i don't actually have a wantsaoc attribute in my model. It is just a method that and a parameter in my view I use to pass additional parameters...